# Should I use the same data transfer object from the server to the client and back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, client-server, dto

I am returning data from different domain repositories to my service and from the service to my Asp.net WebApi controller to the client. The data is put into a DTO.

Should I use the same DTO to transfer the data from the client to server although I would have to add some properties which are not used from server to client.

Is that approach ok or should I use different DTO`s ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP, and therefore WebAPI, deal in Requests and Responses. Its a matter of opinion, but I would venture that if there is even a small difference I would go ahead and make individual objects/DTOs to echo the HTTP request & response design in your code.

This would also adhere to the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Ok lets assume I do 2 DTOs. Would you then make a base class and how would you name the DTOs ? CustomerRequestDTO/CustomerRespondDTO?

Comment: Yep, I would go with Request/Response suffixes. A base class is would be a good idea if you think it would mean less maintenance. You mentioned that there are different *domain repositories*? If this is important to the client then you could bring that into the naming convention too.

Comment: Ok I named it CustomerResponse/CustomerRequest with a base class and put that in a folder called DTO.